# Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target in React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

there

I'm trying to open native modal on iOS in **React Native.**

The result I wanted was a screen like the one below.

[image]

But I got the following error:

`Thread 1: "Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <UIViewController: 0x7f904f811290>.`

I don't know much about object-c, so I searched the internet for it, and eventually asked a question.

How can I solve it?

Here is one of the **stack traces**:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a5a1bb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a2abbe7 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2c5b95 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 6177
    3   UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2c6520 __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 98
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2c6856 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 519
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2c647e -[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 173
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000011b2c690c -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 155
    7   Awesome                             0x0000000100243d7b __19-[Buzzvil openFeed]_block_invoke + 203
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d6a28 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d7c0c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7e6376 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1195
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a50f85d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a50a0ba __CFRunLoopRun + 2772
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a509103 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011316ccd3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    15  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ba6be63 -[UIApplication _run] + 928
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ba70a53 UIApplicationMain + 101
    17  Awesome                             0x0000000100244518 main + 104
    18  dyld                                0x00000001089d5e1e start_sim + 10
    19  ???                                 0x00000002005f64fe 0x0 + 8596186366
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Here is my problematic code ( Buzzvil.m )

```
#import "Buzzvil.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@import BuzzAdBenefit;

@interface Buzzvil ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) BZVBuzzAdFeed *buzzAdFeed;

@end

@implementation Buzzvil

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _buzzAdFeed = [BZVBuzzAdFeed feedWithBlock:^(BZVBuzzAdFeedBuilder * _Nonnull builder) {}];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(logEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"fire event xocde log %@ at %@", name, location);
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(messageEvent:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  callback(@[@"hello from native ios"]);
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setUserEvent:(NSString *)userId gender:(NSString *)gender birth:(NSString *)birth)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"id= %@ <> gender= %@ <> birth= %@", userId, gender, birth);
  NSString *male = @"M";

  [BuzzAdBenefit loginWithBlock:^(BZVLoginRequestBuilder * _Nonnull builder) {
    builder.userId = userId;
    builder.birthYear = [birth intValue];
    builder.gender = [gender isEqualToString:male] ? BZVUserGenderMale : BZVUserGenderFemale;
  } onSuccess:^{
      RCTLogInfo(@"on Success!!");
  } onFailure:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
      RCTLogInfo(@"on Error!!");
  }];
}


// An error occurs when the function below is executed.
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(openFeed)
{ 
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIViewController *rootviewcontroller= [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    BZVFeedViewController *feedViewController = [self->_buzzAdFeed viewController];
    [rootviewcontroller presentViewController:feedViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
  });
}
@end
```

and here is Buzzvil.h file

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface Buzzvil : UIViewController<RCTBridgeModule>
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *rootViewController;

@end
```

Comment: The error mentions that you're trying to present a nil view controller modally. Seems like your feedViewController here is nil: `BZVFeedViewController *feedViewController = [self->_buzzAdFeed viewController];` I would recommend checking how your initializing it in viewDidLoad and confirm that it's properly working there.

Comment: @R4N
thx your comments! 
I got a hint from your comments and solved the problem.